# Como descargar un archivo con PHP

Tags: php, url

### **Hola y Feliz año nuevo para todos**

hoy tengo una pregunta como puedo hacer un script para descargar un archivo de un url y cambiar el nombre del archivo con php este es mi codigo espero que me ayudan y gracias

```
<?php

$headers = "https://r8---sn-0opoxu-gxml.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=289B43A5B01E7928A020EC2DDB921E61972D217A.6872F3E478AEFF627E06D93BBBF0610B870A2887&source=youtube&clen=5920214&expire=1514879772&initcwndbps=306250&itag=17&key=yt6&ei=vOZKWutvg8a4BcfanqgG&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,usequic,expire&mn=sn-0opoxu-gxml&mm=31&ip=187.195.231.38&dur=593.780&id=o-AF9C8zlg_rItNY5MwJb5pg3J8q40F3RcUzKMFsddxZkx&mime=video/3gpp&ms=au&requiressl=yes&pl=19&mv=m&mt=1514858069&usequic=no&gir=yes&ipbits=0&lmt=1514857104023208";
$url= basename($headers);
$fileName = 'video.3gp';
if(!empty($url)){
    // Define headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // Read the file
    readfile($fileName);
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si generaras un archivo desde tu propio servidor en forma interna, tu ejemplo te podría servir, pero si lo que quieres es descargar un archivo externo y renombrarlo puedes usar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php
$nuevo_nombre = 'nuevo_nombre'; //asignamos nuevo nombre
$archivo_descarga = curl_init(); //inicializamos el curl
curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://pluspng.com/img-png/php-384.png'); //ponemos lo que queremos descargar
//curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$resultado_descarga = curl_exec($archivo_descarga); //realizamos la descarga
if(!curl_errno($archivo_descarga)) // si no hay error hacemos la descarga
{
  header('Content-type:image/png'); //Acá le cambias el tipo de archivo (MimeType) por lo que quieras
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ="'.$nuevo_nombre.'.png"'); //renombramos la descarga
  echo($resultado_descarga);
  exit();
}else
{
  echo(curl_error($archivo_descarga)); // Si hay error lo mostramos
}
?>
```

Para hacer funcionar el ejemplo anterior deberás tener la extensión cURL activa.  Si no sabes como activarla, busca como activar cURL en php en internet.

Es mejor hacerlo así, ya que es mejor habilitar esa extensión que estar modificando configuraciones sensibles de tu servidor que podrían ponerlo en riesgo.

Date una vuelta por acá para que veas las opciones disponibles de la extensión cURL:
http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php

Comment: gracias amigo :)